Android Studio: SDK Path Contains Non-ASCII Characters Causing Issues
enter image description here|
I'm experiencing an issue with Android Studio related to the SDK path. My SDK path contains non-ASCII characters, which seems to be causing problems with Android Studio recognizing the SDK. I've tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Moved the SDK to a new path containing only ASCII characters (e.g., C:\Android\SDK).

Updated the ANDROID_HOME and PATH environment variables to point to the new SDK path.

Reinstalled Android Studio and set the language to English (United States).

Cleaned the caches in Android Studio by using "Invalidate Caches / Restart".

Ensured all SDK tools are up to date via the SDK Manager.


Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Android Studio still fails to recognize the SDK.
What else can I try to resolve this issue? Are there any additional settings or configurations I might be missing?
Thank you for your assistance.
